# Two separate Linux SCST setups generating same UUIDs

Tags: linux, iscsi

I have setup SCST in two different linux setups. 
Config file 1:

```
HANDLER vdisk_fileio {
    DEVICE disk01 {
            # create mdisk using "fallocate -l 1G test.img"
            filename /root/test.bin
    }
}
HANDLER vdisk_nullio {
    DEVICE disk_null
}  

TARGET_DRIVER iscsi {
    enabled 1

    TARGET iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:867231fb5ac  {
            # Local IP on which listen to start
            allowed_portal 192.168.57.30
            allowed_portal 192.168.57.23

            QueuedCommands 128
            LUN 0 disk01
            enabled 1
    }

}
```

Config file 2:

```
HANDLER vdisk_fileio {
    DEVICE disk01 {
            filename /root/hello.img
            nv_cache 1
    }
}
TARGET_DRIVER iscsi {
    enabled 1

    TARGET iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:831de6212b18  {
            allowed_portal 192.168.57.21
            QueuedCommands 128
            LUN 0 disk01
            enabled 1
    }
}
```

When the initiator logs into both the setups, the UUID returned for the disks from different setups is same and the initiator considers the mapped disks as single disk.
Is there any way to change the UUID of the disk for SCST by adding some parameters in scst.conf file. 
I tried changing the UUID using blkid/uuidgen APIs but the requires the device to be in /dev directory.

I have used dd command to create both the disks.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem UUID is the same on both of the block devices you're serving out. That has nothing to do with SCST (as your problem a layer above what SCST cares about), and is the same on both volumes because you copied their filesystems 1:1 using `dd`.

It really matters what filesystem type they are formatted as, as you can change the UUID of most filesystems post-creation. BTRFS is an example of a filesystem that does not support this operation due to its advanced features that utilize UUIDs extensively.

However, ext4 can be changed (while offline) as I described above using a command similar to this: `sudo tune2fs /dev/sde5 -U $(uuidgen)`. If you can't do this to the block device on the SCST side (you'd have to turn off the target to unlock the block device), then perform this operation on an initiator.

If you don't want to deal with this in the future, you'll need to re-think your `dd` approach and consider using something like a file based copy to do whatever it is you're trying to accomplish. However, a block copy and then re-label / re-uuid has the potential to be faster than copying a lot of small files.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer but if the problem was dd, creating two files using dd on the same system should have also resulted in the same problem. But in that case, for a single SCST target having two files as LUNs(created with dd), we are getting different UUID.

Comment: [cleaning up the conversation from above, pasting it here] I made an answer primarily concerning filesystem UUIDs. However, I'm uncertain whether this question is confusing filesystem UUIDs for SCSI IDs. Are you worrying about the ID of the block device itself or the filesystem on the block devices? You refer to using `dd` to create your LUN backing devices, which increases my suspicion that you may be referring to SCSI ID or SCSI serial, which are a part of the Vital Product Data and can be explicitly set within the target configuration. This would usually only be a concern for multipathing.